# Facebook Dialog Feed (display parameter not working)

Tags: facebook

I've followed the documentation to add Facebook feed dialog to my site.  My one issue is that the dialog is not opening as a popup, even though I am setting the display parameter to "popup".

```
<a class="facebook_icon" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=264179898666332&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://mysite.com/&message=I use Mysite!"></a>
```

I realize that, to display it as an iframe, I need to get user permission to obtain an access key.  I just want to show the dialog as a separate window for the time being.

Any clue why this isn't working? Is the general consensus that I should just use the iframe now for UX's sake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
<a class="facebook_icon" href="" target="_blank"></a>
```

Don't forget that you can always use the `FB.ui` method. Just go to the [test console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/), click on examples and choose "feed" under "FB.ui":

```
var publish = {
  method: 'feed',
  message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg'
};

FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('feed callback'));
```

Comment: Thank ifaour. I could use FB.ui.  I was more curious why the parameter is clearly not working for me.  If i just use a target attr there, will I be able to resize the window? Right now, I'm using js to open in a new window (and resize).

Answer (score 6):

I thought I had this issue for quite a while before I discovered that `display=popup` **does not open the dialog as a popup, rather it formats the dialog so that it looks good in a popup**.

I ended up using Javascript to open it in a new window - something like this:

```
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=264179898666332&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://mysite.com/&message=I use Mysite!",
                            "My Window Name", 
                            "height=236, width=516");
```

You will notice that if you now switch the display between `display=popup` and `display=page`, the *popup* formatting looks much better than the *page* formatting if you're displaying it in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

According the Facebook documentation for "display modes" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/), the "popup" attribute does not automatically create your popup for you, instead it just formats content on the page such that the content looks best in a 'popup'

They key wording is "For use in a browser popup no bigger than 400px by 580px". They are suggesting you use javascript to invoke a popup and format that popup no larger than 400 by 580

```
facebook_share_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=' + window.settings_fb_key + '&link=' + merchant_url + '&redirect_uri=' + merchant_url + '&display=popup'
window.open(facebook_share_url,'','width=400,height=580')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it works

```
FB.init({appId: "Your AppId",show_error:true, status: true, cookie: true}); 

  function postToFeed() { 

    // calling the API ... 
    var obj = { 
      method: 'feed', 
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/', 
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg', 
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs', 
      caption: 'Reference Documentation', 
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.' 
    }; 

    FB.ui(obj, callback); 
  } 

    function callback(response)  
{ 

    }
```